# How to update the files locally after a rollback on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, rollback

I have, let's say 10 deployments on Heroku of a web application;
I would like to rollback to the 6th release

The first step is to rollback on Heroku, then I have to git clone the web application through this command

```
heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

My question is, how to update the developpment files, **locally**, do I have to delete manually all the folders and the files of the app, and replaced them by the folders and files downloaded from git clone ? does the Git will remain the same ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Running on a rolled-back release is meant as a [temporary fix](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback) to a bad deployment."

In order to rollback your code you have a [few different options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit). Just note that the `--hard` flag will destroy any local modifications.

Comment: thank you, just an important question for me, if I execute "git reset --hard xxxx", will the local files be updated automatically (with the previous Git) ? many thanks

Comment: Yes. So just be careful to not overwrite any new code.